# Ansible search and query

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

Updated with suggestions from larsks.
With the following structure

```
    "intf_output_ios": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "gathered": [
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet0/0"
            },
            {
                "mode": "trunk",
                "name": "GigabitEthernet0/1",
                "trunk": {
                    "allowed_vlans": [
                        "10",
                        "20",
                        "30",
                        "99",
                        "100"
                    ],
                    "encapsulation": "dot1q"
                }
            },
            {
                "mode": "trunk",
                "name": "GigabitEthernet0/2",
                "trunk": {
                    "allowed_vlans": [
                        "10",
                        "20",
                        "30",
                        "99",
                        "100"
                    ],
                    "encapsulation": "dot1q"
                }
            },
            {
                "access": {
                    "vlan": 30
                },
                "mode": "access",
                "name": "GigabitEthernet0/3"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet1/0"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet1/1"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet1/2"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet1/3"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet2/0"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet2/1"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet2/2"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet2/3"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet3/0"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet3/1"
            },
            {
                "name": "GigabitEthernet3/2"
            },
            {
                "access": {
                    "vlan": 99
                },
                "mode": "access",
                "name": "GigabitEthernet3/3"
            }
        ]
    }
```

To print only the ports in  VLAN 30 use the following?

```
- name: "P901T6: Set fact to include only access ports - IOS"
  set_fact:
    access_ports_ios_2: "{{ intf_output_ios | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: >-
      gathered[?access.vlan==`30`]

- name: "P901T7: Dump list of access ports - IOS"
  debug:
    var=access_ports_ios_2
```

NOTE: It is important to use `30` (with backticks) and not '30'

I have gone through https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables without really understanding how to fix this.  If someone has some good link that would be very useful

With a structure like

```
ok: [access01] => {
    "access_ports_ios": [
        {
            "access": {
                "vlan": 30
            },
            "mode": "access",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/3"
        },
        {
            "access": {
                "vlan": 99
            },
            "mode": "access",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet3/3"
        }
    ]
}
```

To get ports in vlan 30 use:

```
- debug:
    var: access_ports_ios|json_query(query)
  vars:
    query: >-
      [?access.vlan==`30`]
```

Note:
If you want to use a variable for vlan instead of hard-coding it. I had to do as follows:

```
- name: Debug 4
  debug:
    var: access_ports_ios|json_query('[?access.vlan==`{{ src_vlan | int}}`]')
```

Comment: @larsks Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for `gathered.access`, but `gathered` is a list and does not have an `access` attribute. You want "all items from `gathered` for which `access.vlan` is `30` (and note that the value of `access.vlan` is an *integer*, not a string):

```
- debug:
    var: intf_output_ios|json_query(query)
  vars:
    query: >-
      gathered[?access.vlan==`30`]
```

Which given you example input produces:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "intf_output_ios|json_query(query)": [
        {
            "access": {
                "vlan": 30
            },
            "mode": "access",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/3"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

I'm going to reiterate advice I often give for `json_query` questions: use something like [`jpterm`](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.terminal) or the [JMESPath website](https://jmespath.org/) to test JMESPath expressions against your actual data. This makes it much easier to figure out where an expression might be going wrong.

Comment: is there a difference between: gathered[?access.vlan==`30`] and gathered[?access.vlan=='30'] ? only the one you use works

Comment: Well, right, that's the difference :). The backtick is for quoting JSON literals, so using backticks the quoted value is interpreted as an integer (while using single quotes would make it a string, which would fail to match).

Comment: I have updated question with your suggestions.  For completeness can you take a look at sames information structure differently, could not find any example to search  that structure

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking; the answer here shows how to get a list of ports on vlan 30. What do you need that's not included here already?

Comment: I figured out and updated the question with what works for alternate structure.